# Is X connected by paths?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

I have the following space $X=[0,1) \cup \{y,z\}$ with $y \neq z$ and $y,z \notin [0,1)$.

Where the basic open for point in $[0,1)$ are taken as the basics to the topology that R inherits to the space.

The basics opens for $y$ are the sets of the form $\{y\} \cup (b,1)$, where $b \in (0,1)$.

And the basic open for $z$ are the sets of the form $\{z\} \cup (b,1)$, where $b \in (0,1)$.

I need to prove that $X$ is path connected.
My definition of path-connected is that for any two points $p,q \in X$, there exists $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ continuous such that $f(0)=p$ and $f(1)=q$.

Could someone help me find this function?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Prove that :

- for any $x \in [0,1)$, the path $\gamma_x : [0,1] \rightarrow X$ defined for all $t \in [0,1]$ by $\gamma_x(t)=tx$ is a continuous path joining $0$ to $x$,
- the path $\gamma_y: [0,1] \rightarrow X$ defined by

$$\forall t \in [0,1), \ \gamma_y(t)=t \quad \text{and} \quad \gamma_y(1)=y$$
$\quad\ $ is a continuous path joining $0$ to $y$,

- the path $\gamma_z: [0,1] \rightarrow X$ defined by

$$\forall t \in [0,1), \ \gamma_z(t)=t \quad \text{and} \quad \gamma_z(1)=z$$ $\quad\ $ is a continuous path joining $0$ to $z$.